# Complex Declaration of Sizeof operator in C

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor, sizeof

I have seen this complex declaration of sizeof operator somewhere in book which is teasing me:

```
#define SIZEOF(int)  (int)&((int *)0)[1]
```

Can any one explain this declaration,  whats going on here...?

Comment: Please give the name/author of the book so that others may avoid it.

Comment: reminds me of what I used to find in this book: http://www.amazon.com/The-Puzzle-Book-Alan-Feuer/dp/0201604612/ref=la_B001IXRU2O_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1338723178&sr=1-1

Comment: I suspect that what *actually* appears in the (probably also suspect) book is more like: `#define SIZEOF(T)  (int)&((T *)0)[1]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here it is with the `[1]` part 'expanded':

```
(int)(&(*(((int*)0) + 1)))
```

Now do you see how it works?

The 0 will increase by the `sizeof` `int` due to the properties of pointer arithmetic and the final `int` cast is getting you the value of the resulting address which is the 'size'.

It's totally undefined behavior though (the arithmetic on null and possibly the dereference of invalid pointer), fairly pointless.

---

The update with the macro parameter doesn't make much sense. The final cast should probably be `std::uintptr_t`.

Comment: Note that `int` is the macro parameter

Comment: -1: Converting `[]` to `*(x+y)` is not part of "expansion", confusing here because it deals with macros, you need to provide arguments to expand a macro, and it's useless to say "UB" without providing a reason. In this case, the only source of unqualified UB is integral overflow, which makes no difference.

Comment: @PaulR Yep, which will lead to hilarious fun when `SIZEOF(struct foo)` is called.

Comment: @PaulR Ah, seems the question was edited. The macro makes even less sense now.

Comment: @Potatoswatter Isn't the invalid pointer deference technically UB even though the address is taken immediately after? (I recall discussing this before but I forgot the answer)

Comment: Looks like the OP posted a half-remembered version of the macro and not that actually appears in the book.

Comment: @Pubby C++11 changed the object model, it depends what constitutes an access to an object (C++11 3.10/10). Not sure, again this is a sort of UB which never actually made a difference.

Comment: @Potatoswatter KonradRudolph says it can crash on MSVC, dunno if that's changed since C++11.

Comment: @Pubby: this has been argued all over the place, including IIRC in defect reports on both C and C++. I think that C90 says that `&*<some pointer>` *doesn't* dereference the pointer, that C++03 doesn't explicitly say whether it does or not, but sort of implies that it does. But I can't be bothered to check. Anyway, it's UB to even perform the pointer arithmetic `((T*)0)+1`. You can only validly perform pointer arithmetic within an array (up to and including the one-past-the-end pointer). An object counts as an array of size 1 for this purpose, but a null pointer doesn't point to any object.

Comment: So for example, a conforming implementation could use the max value of a pointer as its null pointer, and chuck a hardware fault if pointer arithmetic overflows. Not that any implementation ever will, so you'd sort of expect this to work (especially on an implementation that implements `offsetof` in the usual way). Still it's true to say that it's UB. I'm pretty sure that `#define SIZEOF sizeof` would be more portable :-)

Answer (score 4):

First -- it's confusing things with the term `int` -- we naturally assume that to be the keyword of a familiar type, however in this case it's not -- instead, it's the argument to the macro. So to simplify, consider the macro as follows:

```
#define SIZEOF(type)  &((type *)0)[1]
```

Now looking at it this way, it's perhaps easier to see that the macro is first casting address 0 to be a pointer to `type`, and then it's taking the address of the second element. This will reveal the size.

Comment: Nice that you spotted the confusing argument name!

Comment: +1 for pointing out the confusing use of `int` as a macro parameter - the other answers posted so far have not spotted this

Answer (score 1):

It defines `SIZEOF` as the size of an integer.

- `(int *)0` is an int pointer at address zero
- `[1]` accesses the *next* integer after that one.
- Since `(int *)0` has the address zero, the one after it has the address `sizeof int` as it comes right after the previous one.
- `(int)` casts it to a number since a size is a number, not a pointer.

Obviously it's a nasty hack, one should simply use `sizeof int`.

Comment: Note that `int` is the macro parameter

Comment: @ThiefMaster the pre-edit was `#define SIZEOF  (int)&((int *)0)[1]`. I believe that in this case, `int` is still the macro parameter, but the spacing of the line makes it less obvious. Am I right, or is there some special rule about spacing in macro definitions?

Comment: I guess after whitespace the macro itself begins.